Jibx-maven-plugin JDK 17 support
I am trying to upgrade Java from version 8 to 17.
I am getting some error related to jibx-maven-plugin.
I am using the jibx-maven-plugin to generate xml bindings from the .xsd files.
Earlier I was using maven-jibx-plugin but I guess now it has been renamed to jibx-maven-plugin.
With the latest version as 1.4.2 for jibx-maven-plugin.
Depending on the versions of bcel dependency version the error chnages.
For version version less than equal to 6.5.0 i get some error related to wrong name and some of the files related to like JiBX_bindings_addmultielements_queryMungeAdapter are not getting genertaed.
For Bcel version above 6.5.0:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jibx:maven-jibx-plugin:1.3.1:bind(compile-binding) on project ac-oneaxml:
                                                                                                                                       [ERROR] *** Error during code generation for file

[ERROR]  this may be due to an error in your binding or classpath, or to an error in the JiBX code

[ERROR] : LocalVariableTable name index programming error: max 65,536 > 65,535  

What could be the solution for this?


Update JiBX and Dependencies:

Ensure you are using the latest version of the jibx-maven-plugin. As of now, the latest version is 1.4.2.
Update the bcel dependency to a compatible version. For Java 17, you might need to use a version higher than 6.5.0. However, be cautious as versions above 6.5.0 might introduce other issues.
2.Check for Known Issues and Fixes:
There are known issues with JiBX and newer Java versions. You might find relevant discussions and potential fixes in the JiBX GitHub issues page1.
3.Modify Plugin Configuration:
Adjust the plugin configuration in your pom.xml to ensure compatibility. Here is an example configuration:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
  <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>bind</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
      <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>

4.Use Alternative Tools:
If the issue persists, consider using alternative tools for XML binding that are known to be compatible with Java 17, such as JAXB.
5.Debugging and Logs:
Enable verbose logging for the plugin to get more detailed error messages. This can help identify the exact cause of the issue:
<configuration>
  <verbose>true</verbose>
</configuration>


This seems to be AI generated. AI generated content is banned in [so].

This may be AI-generated, but it is good advice. Upgrade to JIBX 1.4.2. This will probably fix your problem.
